# Sitecore extranet login?

Tags: sitecore

I am trying to get the below code to work, but with no luck;

```cs
bool success = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(UserName.Text, Password.Text);
if (success)
{           
    string path = Request.QueryString["path"];   
    Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.Redirect(String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) ? "/" : path);
}
```

success is always false, eventhough i know that the entered username and password is correct and created on the extranet domain.

What am i missing?

(It's a Sitecore 6.2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd  guess that the `LoginManager` needs the full username including the domain. So try:

```cs
bool success = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(
   "extranet\\" + UserName.Text, Password.Text);
```

Comment: I'll add my comment here instead:
To login a Sitecore user, the domain must be "sitecore\"